Tomcat Server doesn't start with Https configuration "Tag number over 30 is not supported"
I am trying to convert from http to https in my server
So I created self-signed certificate using keytool in jdk 17 and this is the version I use to run my server
This is the command I use to generate the certificate
keytool -genkeypair -alias tdf -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore tdf.p12 -validity 3650
and I added it in the resources path to be accessed through classpath
and this is my configuration in the properties file
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:tdf.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password

But I faced this exception when the tomcat server trying to attach connector with Tls to it
2024-08-15 09:58:23 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:946)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:594)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1289)
    at com.ejada.tdf.requests.management.TDFRequestsManagementApisApplication.main(TDFRequestsManagementApisApplication.java:23)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:179)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:235)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1042)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:232)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tag number over 30 is not supported
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:236)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1332)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1418)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1039)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Tag number over 30 is not supported
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:442)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:487)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2012)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.security.KeyStoreUtil.load(KeyStoreUtil.java:67)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:240)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:308)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:268)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)
    ... 26 common frames omitted

I tried to change the type of the certificate to JKS but same issue happens also
and checked that the certificate not corrupted using KeyStore Explorer app and I created also dummy project and added this certificate to it and it's successfully running

I don't think keytool from jdk generates suitable certificates for HTTPS servers. Keytool is a tool for generating Java code signing keys. There are various tutorials that show how to generate a server cert using openssl.
